# How to promise correctly ( Angular )

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i write a simple promise in angular for me. Both are nearly same, calling HTTP GET.

Why I did it:
First endpoint is under my controle but the second one is some old and slow WS and I want to display user his data instatly atleast from my endpoint and just add rest of the data after

- 1th endpoint - Take around 45ms sec to get response - getData()
- 2th endpoint - Take is problematic and take around 2,5 - 3 sec- getSoapData()

How i did it:

```
 function getData() {
        var myPromise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'URL' + $scope.vin,
            headers: {Authorization: 'TOKEN'}
        });
        return myPromise;
    };

    function getSoapData() {
        var myPromise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'URL=' + $scope.vin,
            headers: {Authorization: 'TOKEN'}
        });
        return myPromise;
    };

    $scope.findCases = function () {
        getData().then(function (data) {
            $scope.cases = data.data;
            getSoapData().then(function (soapData) {
                $scope.soapCases = soapData.data;
            });
        });
    };
```

Where is a problem:
Somehow I see in my application that promise work because it display me first result from getData and after that from getSoapData however i have problem with time:
When I query just `getData` network say it takes 45ms as mentioned above when i use this `findCases` and call both network tab in browser says 2,7s `getData` and 45 ms  `getSoapData`

I expect i didnt create my promise correctly or I did some other lame mystake but can't find what is it.
Any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: Looking at findCases function getSoapData is nowhere dependent on getData. Why do you wan't to chain them?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're interpreting the network data correctly. I don't see anything wrong with your promise other than I'm not sure why you aren't calling both endpoints asynchronously.

Wouldn't this be preferable:

```
function displayData(result) {
    $scope.cases = result.data;
}

function displaySoap(result) {
    $scope.soapCases = result.data;
}

$scope.findCases = function() {
    getData().then(displayData);
    getSoapData().then(displaySoap);
}
```

This way both calls are made at the same time giving you a faster response to your soap call by avoiding the wait for the first call to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine promises so they'd run in parallel, like this:

```
var promise1 = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'URL' + $scope.vin,
    headers: {Authorization: 'TOKEN'}
});
var promise2 = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'URL=' + $scope.vin,
    headers: {Authorization: 'TOKEN'}
});

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data){
  $scope.cases = data[0].data;
  $scope.soapCases = data[1].data;
});
```

Comment: That means the entire chain needs to resolve before any data is shown, exactly what the OP wants to avoid.